# unable to connect to localhost after allowing permissions for the google app

Tags: python, docker, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I want to implement a simple application that would allow me to access Google Drive. I am following [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python). I run the application in the Docker.

However when I run the script it shows me `Please visit this URL to authorize this application:`. If I go by the URL it asks me to Choose Account, shows warning regarding it not being a verified app (I ignore it and go my app page), asks for access to google drive and metadata (I allow it), and then it redirects me to `http://localhost:46159/?state=f..` and it shows `unable to connect` page. Port may differ.

What is the problem? Is there a way to prevent the application running in Docker to ask for verification?

Comment: 1 you will always have to ask a user for access to their data.  2 your application will display as non verified to the user until you have gone though the verification process.  Neither of these things have anything to do with the fact that you are hosting this on docker

Comment: So no chance to have an app that would access my drive and list the files without annoying process of allowing access each time?

Comment: @DaImTo and regarding docker. Authentications redirects me to localhost with some port. But I am only running the docker app so it redirects me to the docker.

Comment: The docker container should be set up to be a web url.  You need to set your redirect URI in your code to that.  YOu cant redirect to the Localhost on the docker container you need to have an outside address google can access

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to avoid the "asking for verification" process you can instead use authorisation through **service accounts**.

In order to do so, firstly we have to create the service account:

1. Navigate to your GCP project.
2. Go to `Credentials`
3. Click on Create credentials>Service account key
4. Set the service account name, ID and Role (if applicable). Leave the Key type as JSON.
5. Click on `Create`. A JSON file will be downloaded containing the credentials of the newly created Service account.

Now, copy the file to the folder holding your project and use the following modified code (based on the Quickstart example you used):

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/service.json'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
   creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that Service Accounts behave like normal accounts (they have their own files, permissions, etc.). If you want a service account to act like an existing user of your domain, you can manage to do so by using [Domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation).

### Reference

- [Create a service account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)
- [Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

Comment: so basically aside creating `service account` I have to use domain-wide delegation to provide access to my google drive folders

Comment: @lapots that is correct. Alternatively, you could share the folder with the service account (you can do that as you would share it with any other user in your domain - by specifying the account email) and upload the files to it. This alternative would probably be safer, as Domain-Wide delegation could impose security risks in case the service account is compromised. Cheers

Comment: I also have to create a GSuite account? regular it seems does not work.